# Print only words with Capital Letters (Linux)

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

So I am currently reading from this txt file:

```
Line 961: www-d1.proxy.aol.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:35:32 -0400] "GET /elv/hot.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1007
Line 965: www-d1.proxy.aol.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:35:41 -0400] "GET /elv/PEGASUS/minpeg1.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1055
Line 966: www-d1.proxy.aol.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:35:46 -0400] "GET /elv/SCOUT/scout.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1165
Line 969: www-d1.proxy.aol.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:35:49 -0400] "GET /elv/DELTA/delta.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2244
Line 972: www-d1.proxy.aol.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:35:51 -0400] "GET /elv/ATLAS_CENTAUR/atlas.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2286
Line 95219: u139.n72.queensu.ca - - [04/Aug/1995:10:40:04 -0400] "GET /elv HTTP/1.0" 302 -
```

And I am trying to print out only the names in the command line(basically only the ones in capital letters) WITH NO DUPLICATES. For example:

```
ATLAS_CENTAUR
DELTA
SCOUT
PEGASUS
```

My codes so far:

```
grep "/elv" ~/spacestation.txt | awk -F/ '{print $5}' | sort -u
```

Actual output:

```
1.0" 302
ATLAS_CENTAUR
DELTA
hot.gif HTTP
SCOUT
PEGASUS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put regex pattern in your awk script to compare $5:

Solution:

```
grep "/elv" ~/spacestation.txt | awk -F/ '$5 ~ /^[A-Z_]+/ {print $5}' | sort -u
```

1. '~' is for compare $5 with regex pattern matching
2. '^' is first character of word
3. '[A-Z_]' will look for all caps-lock characters including with _
4. '+' is for to continue with matching [A-Z_] if he finds one or more character like this

Comment: sorry i forgot to say, duplicates cannot be printed out

Comment: Apparently theres a "SELV" & "SELV HTTP". any idea how i can remove the selv http?

Comment: Solution for "SELV" & "SELV HTTP":     grep "/elv" ~/spacestation.txt | awk -F/ '$5 ~ /^[A-Z_]+/ {print $5}' | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
your_command | awk '
match($0,/"GET \/[a-zA-Z]+\/[^/]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*\//,"",val)
  if(val!~/[a-z]/){  print val  }
  val=""
}'
```

Comment: sorry sorry i forgot to mention, im trying to execute this in one command only with grep, awk, print, sed and pipelines. sorry!

Comment: @Kinja, no issues, please try my edited command, pass your command's output by pipe as standard input for this awk command, should work then, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Single command line:

```
grep -E '/elv/[A-Z]+' infile | sed -E 's:.*/elv/([A-Z_]+).*:\1:'
```

if `sort` is needed/allowed,

```
 grep -E '/elv/[A-Z]+' infile | sed -E 's:.*/elv/([A-Z_]+).*:\1:' | sort -u
```

Comment: OH RIGHT I FORGOT SAY, i cannot print out any duplicates.

Comment: You can almost always refactor `grep 'x' | sed 's/y/z/'` into `sed -n '/x/s/y/z/p'`. If `x` is equal to - or can be refactored to - `y`, you only need `/y/s//z/p`. See also [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm wrong… but why not simply?

```sh
sed -ne "s_.*/elv/\([A-Z_]\+\).*_\1_p" <(cat spacestation.txt) | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

In `awk` you can do the following.

- set FS separator and print:

`awk -v FS="/elv/" '{print $2}' file`

```
hot.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1007
PEGASUS/minpeg1.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1055
SCOUT/scout.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1165
DELTA/delta.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2244
ATLAS_CENTAUR/atlas.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2286
```

- you see that `NR>1` doesn't print the first record

`awk -v FS="/elv/" 'NR>1{print $2}' file`

```
PEGASUS/minpeg1.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1055
SCOUT/scout.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1165
DELTA/delta.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2244
ATLAS_CENTAUR/atlas.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2286
```

- and the `split()` function gets what you want:

`awk -v FS="/elv/" 'NR>1{split($2,a,/\//);print a[1]}' file`

```
PEGASUS
SCOUT
DELTA
ATLAS_CENTAUR
```

- Finally, I invite you to remove possible duplicates and/or put the result in alphabetical order searching by yourself: these 'how to...' are repeated in internet. This url can help: https://iridakos.com/programming/2019/05/16/remove-duplicate-lines-preserving-order-linux